# Update Columns with Using Case

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-update, case

i have an asp.net project,on this project,

i need to update my column according to values of my other 2 columns.
Structure of my table looks ;

ID - NAME - GK - PG - GK+PG

1  - mike  - 1 - 1   [the sql should write here 540 but writes 180 for the case]

2  - john  - 2 - 1   [the sql should write here 1080 but writes 180 for the case]

3  - sue  -  1 - 2   [the sql should write here 1080 but writes 180 for the case]

Here is the .cs code for it.

```
string strSQL = "UPDATE [info] SET
[GK_PG] = (CASE
WHEN ([GK]='1') THEN '180'
WHEN ([PG]='1') THEN '180'
WHEN ([GK]='2') THEN '540'
WHEN ([PG]='2') THEN '540'
WHEN ([GK]='3') THEN '1080'
WHEN ([PG]='3') THEN '1080'
WHEN ([GK]='1' AND [PG]='1') THEN '540'
WHEN ([GK]='2' AND [PG]='1') THEN '1080'
WHEN ([GK]='1' AND [PG]='2') THEN '1080'
ELSE 0
END)
WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN @DATE1 AND @DATE1 AND WORK_TYPE='IN'";
```

This code just writes the my [GK_PG] column '180', it doesnt look for other statuses.

Waiting your answer.

Thank you.

Comment: If all rows have either `[GK]='1'` or `[PG]='1'`, this is expected. The 3rd and following conditions would not be checked in this case.

Comment: i need to check them, how can i do that my friend ?

Comment: First check for AND conditions then use OR.

Comment: `CASE` expression checks every condition until it finds a true one, then stops. Show us an example row that gets a wrong update.

Comment: So, i cannot make that sql to check other conditions ?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add a few rows? The `CASE` will - and for every row - check all conditions until it finds a true one.

Comment: i need to check all conditions and writes the right one.. if its gk = 1, pg = 1 it should write on gk_pg = 540.. like this goes on..

Comment: Move the last 3 conditions (`WHEN ([GK]='1' AND [PG]='1') THEN '540'
WHEN ([GK]='2' AND [PG]='1') THEN '1080'
WHEN ([GK]='1' AND [PG]='2') THEN '1080'`) to the 1st place, just after the `CASE`.

Comment: but if gk=1 pg=null what's going to happen my friend ? or gk='null' pg = 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by seperating GK and PG situations into the 2 different button click event.

Thanks anyway.